# jaxb marxshalling - duplicate elements in the xml

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I have two objects that are in hierarchical relationship. I have the jaxb mapping for setter methods in the child pojo. While loading the xml into pojo  I don't have any issues. However, while generating the xml, I see two element entries in the xml for the same attribute in pojo the object - one with the mapping key and the other with actual variable name.

Example:
    //parent class

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
       return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
       this.name=name;
    }

}

//second class 
@XmlRootElement(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher extends Employee {

    @Override
    public String getName(){
       return super.getName();
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name ="NAME")
    public void setName(String name){
       super.setname(name)
    }

}
//xml out put I get is
// like this
<teacher>
    <name>John Doe<name/>
    <NAME>John Doe</NAME>
</teacher>
```

How do I fix this? I want just the one with the key - NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do either:

1. Mark the `name` property on the `Emoloyee` class as `@XmlTransient`.
2. Mark the `Employee` class as `@XmlTransient` to remove it as a mapped class.
3. Remove the `name` property from the `Teacher` class and annotate the one on `Employee` with your `@XmlElement` annotation.